# Jest: How to update a value of a mock function in an onChange method?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In the following code everything works except for the update of the value in the onChange method.

The expected way it should work is:

- initial value is an empty string (✓ works)
- when a change is made the value should be the value of the change (✗ does not work)

```
const mockSetFieldValue = jest.fn(() => '');

beforeAll(async () => {
  field = {
    name: 'password',
    value: mockSetFieldValue(),
    // ^^^ initial value is picked up, but not the change in onChange
    onChange: (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.value) // returns: foo123
      mockSetFieldValue.mockReturnValue(() => e.target.value);
      // ^^^ this does not update the value
    },
  };
  tree = (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <MyField field={field} />
    </>
  );
});

it('input accepts a value', () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(tree);
  const input = getByLabelText(/Password/i);

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'foo123' } });

  expect(input.value).toBe('foo123');
});
```

How would it be possible to update the onChange method to change the value that is set in my component?

I've tried `mockImplementationOnce` and `mockReturnValue`. But they don't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`field.value` is set once before all your tests using the current value of the `mockSetFieldValue` function, which returns the empty string. Changing the `mockSetFieldValue` function therefore has no effect.

You need to be able to set the `field.value` in `onChange`, which you could do like this:

```
onChange: (e) => {
  field.value = e.target.value;
},
```

It is probably better to mock out the whole `onChange` function:

```
const mockOnChange= jest.fn();

beforeAll(async () => {
  field = {
    name: 'password',
    value: '',
    onChange: mockOnChange,
  };
  //...
});
```

Then in the test:

```
mockOnChange.mockImplementationOnce((e) => { field.value = e.target.value });
fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'foo123' } });
```